# Testing using WATIR-webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am going to give presentation on webpage testing using WATIR, but I don't know how to prepare for the demonstration as I don't know any thing about it.

Can anyone suggest a way which I could just perform a testing procedure easily or arrange a test script?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good place to begin

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
browser.goto "https://www.google.com/search?q=watir%20webdriver"
```

Comment: Even this is more than the OP deserved. But very nice indeed.